# Change displayed time range on day view of calendar (SharePoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, view

I have SharePoint online and am trying to customize a calendar view scoped down to the day level. Right now, it shows 7am - 7pm. I would like to have it show 8am - 5pm. How should I approach this?

[image: Regional Settings]

[image: Calendar View]

Comment: from your screen shot its 8AM-5PM? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the 7am - 8am rows along with the 5pm - 7pm rows. So the day view just shows the timeframe from 8am - 5pm.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a calendar setting rather this is the **Regional Settings** of the site. To change

Site Settings -> Regional Settings -> "Define Your Work Week" -> Start Time & End Time

Comment: Amal, my Regional Settings are set to M-F, 8am - 5pm already. The daily scope calendar view still shows from 7am - 7pm.

Comment: Try creating a new calendar and check if that also uses 7 to 7

Comment: It does. I can create a new calendar, go to the day scope and it still shows 7am - 7pm.

Comment: @Jim I am not able to reproduce this on my sharepoint online site. Are you sure you are modifying the correct site setting where you calendar app is? Does you site has any CSS/MasterPage customizations?

Comment: Amal, I have the regional settings applied to all sites within the collection. There is a custom master page that adds a footer to the page and changes the colors/branding of the header top (based off the Oslo master page). Do you know of any CSS or SP Designer settings that might control the hours shown on the day view?

Comment: It has the area of time from 8am - 5pm in white, and the area of time from 7am - 8am and 5pm - 7pm in grey. But it still shows the entire 7am - 7pm range on the day view.

Comment: @Jim oh we will not be able to hide it out of the box. You should use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to solve this problem is by using following CSS:

```
/* restrict time range */
.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(17){
    display: none;
}
.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(18){
    display: none;
}
.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(19){
    display: none;
}
.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(20){
    display: none;
}


.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(37){
    display: none;
}
.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(38){
    display: none;
}
.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(39){
    display: none;
}
.ms-acal-detail tr:nth-child(40){
    display: none;
}
```